# What is an IETLD file?

Tags: computer-forensics

What is an IETLD file?
sir i found this in my browser history while investigating my computer system.is it effective in digital computer forensics.
examples:1. Location: ietld:hotel.lk Number of hits: 1 Cached file size: 0
2.Location: ietld:gob.ni Number of hits: 1 Cached file size: 0, etc
thanks in advance

Comment: Have you done any research? Easily found the answer at https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20121023094825AANyAsS just typing "IEETLD file" into Google.

Answer (score 0):

ie8 creates an "IETldCache" folder in %USERPROFILE%, containing index.dat.

For simply find to the yahoo [answer](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20121023094825AANyAsS).

Comment: Location: ietld:hotel.lk Number of hits: 1 Cached file size: 0 ,,sir buat how i can get information from this entry that site was accessed or sited?